# Converting JS Sorting Function To PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am more of a JS person so I wrote a page using JS. However, I later realized it would probably be better to do 99.9% of the stuff I needed to do server-side, but being rather new to PHP I need some help.

Below is a snippet where I create basically a multi-dimensional array and sort it by one of its inner values:

```
var sortedpts=[];
_.each(main.points,function(v,k){
    sortedpts.push([k,v]);
});
sortedpts.sort(function(a,b){return b[1]-a[1];});
return sortedpts;
```

The whole structure is a long array (over 100 values) where each key contains an array of two values and I wish to sort by the latter of these. If you're confused here is a screenshot/example showing how my JS has sorted the main array by an inner value:

[image: example array structure]

I'm kind of at a loss of how to sort this particular way in PHP. It seems that **array_multisort** may be involved in the solution. Any help?

Comment: [`usort`](http://php.net/usort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I gather all you needed was to be pointed to the right function, here it is again:

JavaScript's "sort by function" is more or less exactly the same as PHP's [`usort`](http://php.net/usort). There are some minor differences (such as how PHP anonymous functions don't inherit the parent scope), but that's not really relevant here.